# Ошибка Class 'mysqli' not found PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Всем привет. Неожиданно появилась ошибка Class 'mysqli' not found, до этого все работало отлично потом при перезагрузке странимцы ни с того ни с сего выскочила ошибка. Каким образом её можно исправить?

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("***", "***", "***", "***");
```

Comment: Вы подключаете переменную global. Зачем вы вызываете new mysqli заново? Должно быть mysqli_connect

Comment: Не могу ответить на этот вопрос, код я брал из видеоурока, мои знания PHP очень скудные

Comment: Вместо чего нужнго вставить mysqli_connect?

Comment: У вас вместо звездочек данные вашей БД ведь? Я надеюсь.

Comment: Да, звездочки для конспирации

Comment: Расширение mysqli включено в php.ini?

Comment: Я не знаю, как это можно проверить? Все работало исправно потом резко вылезка ошибка значит было подключено я полагаю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107752/discussion-between-pekpek-and-youngoldman).

Answer (score 1):

Вероятнее всего не подключен mysqli в php.ini

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Там будет написано где лежит php.ini открываем его. Находим в нём:

```
;extension=php_mysqli
```

или что-то подобное и посмотри нет ли знака ";" если есть, уберите его.

Если РНР запускается из консоли, то смотреть рсположение php.ini командой `php -i`

Comment: Спустся 10 минут ошибка исчезла. Это что за рандом?

Comment: Во время появления ошибка путь к php.ini был один, сейчас другой. Я ничего не менял ни тогда ни сейчас. Как это?

Comment: Путь показываемый в phpinfo() находится на компьютере или на сервере, не понимаю?

Comment: @pekpek, если Вы на хостинге, то у хостинга были проблемы. Если у Вас. То могло быть такое при переключении версии PHP

Comment: Значит проблема с хостингом. Спасибо за помощь